# Why iOS GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition is using older version of FlatBuffers

Tags: ios, security, google-mlkit, flatbuffers, text-recognition

For iOS, in `googlemlkit/textrecognition` version `2.2.0`, the MLKitTextRecognition framework file shows the older version of `FlatBuffers` as follows:

> ... Not enough Too much third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/crypto/x509/x509name.c name= **FlatBuffers 1.11.0** hashtype murmur ...

So I upgraded `googlemlkit/textrecognition` to the latest version i.e. `3.2.0`. Here I see the same FlatBuffers version but in MLKitTextRecognitionCommon framework file as follows:

> ... **FlatBuffers 1.11.0** TfliteRegionProposalTextDetector
> ./ocr/photo/detection/tflite_region_proposal_text_detector.h ...

The question here is, does the quoted text assures that GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition is really  using older version of FlatBuffers. If yes, then how this can be fixed and where can I raise this issue to get it fixed.

Adding some more context to this question. The vulnerability tool is detecting a risk in FlatBuffers v 1.11.0 (which is part of MLKit). The same risk is reported on CVE details on following link: https://www.cvedetails.com/version-list/0/77533/1/?q=Flatbuffers

Comment: Have you tested the 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition' pod, version '4.0.0'? 
Where did you find FlatBuffers 1.11.0? 
In the MLKitTextRecognitionCommon framework, I only found FlatBuffers like: 
- `@automatically generated by the FlatBuffers compiler`
- `@__ZN11flatbuffers13BaseGenerator27FlatBuffersGeneratedWarningEv^`



ML Kit plans to address this in our Q1 2024 release. Your guidance for verification would help us fix this effectively. Thanks

Comment: @JulieZhou I haven't tested 4.0.0 - the latest I see on your page is "pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition', '3.2.0'". To find the FlatBuffers, search the name and version together (FlatBuffers 1.11.0) you will find it in the framework/unix-executable file.